# django pass extra parameters to foreignkey field

Tags: django

I have model like:

```
class Profile(models.Model, DictMixin):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, models.CASCADE, related_name="profile")
    display_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    avatar = models.ForeignKey(MyMedia, models.CASCADE, related_name="avatar", type="profile")

class MyMedia(models.Model):
    media = models.FileField(upload_to="some_dynamic_folder")
```

Here I am having a `ForeignKey` relation of MyMedia to avatar. 
When I upload the file I want it to save to specific folder that I pass as a parameter to ForeignKeyField or Manytomanyfield.

Lets, say all the profile picture should be saved in `profile_picture` field and all the contents should be saved in `content` folder.

Is it possible to do this ?

Need some suggestins :)

Comment: I guess you are trying the same help I'm asking for :D https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54713983/whats-the-modelor-name-who-calls-shared-method-to-save-the-reference

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood, what you want is to save MyMedia files in one folder or another depending on the type? If so, first you could define a type field to MyMedia to differentiate one type or another. Once set, if you set upload_to parameter to a function, you can manipulate the folder. Something like this:

```
def some_dynamic_folder(instance, filename):
    type = instance.type

    if type == "profile":
        return "profile_folder/{}".format(filename)
    elif type == "content":
        return "content_folder/{}".format(filename)


class MyMedia(models.Model):
    TYPES = (
        ("profile", "Profile picture"),
        ("content", "Content picture")
    )
    media = models.FileField(upload_to=some_dynamic_folder)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=TYPES)
```

Then, every time you upload a file, it checks some_dynamic_folder function and return the desire folder depending on the type.

Hope this helps!