# What's the model(or name) who calls shared method to save the reference?

Tags: python, django, inheritance, django-models, django-admin

I have a catalog to save all address from any "form" in django admin (called by models.ForeignKey), with street, number, city, that's Okay - but I want to save the name of field(or class, or filename, something ) that invoked this address method, to save together address information any reference about the source asked for

```
class TraderClass(models.Model):
      trader_ID = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)

      caller #1
      address_enterprise = models.ForeignKey(AddressClass, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=None, verbose_name='Address')


class EnterpriseClass(models.Model):
      enterprise_ID = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)

      caller #2
      address_project = models.ForeignKey(AddressClass, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=None, verbose_name='Address')
```

The Address

```
class AddressClass(models.Model):
    ID = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)

    address_source = models.CharField(max_length=32,
    default=__qualname__,verbose_name='Origin')
```

`\__qualname\__` only shows the same class "AddressClass" I need something like `TraderClass/EnterpriseClass` OR `address_enterprise/address_project` or anything I can save with the address

Comment: I don't think that information is available to the model itself. How many times do you plan on doing this? Can't you just set the correct value yourself when saving the form?

Comment: Since you have a one-to-many relationship (an `Address` can be referenced by multiple instances of type `Trader` or `Enterprise`) there's no way to do this except adding the information when you save the address, i.e. in the form or view.